# my question is about i opened a github project in netbeans when i tried to open its fxml file scene builder says: couldnt open login.fxml file

Tags: java, fxml, builder, scene

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUiNt.png) - java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
       /C:/Users/HabibCse25/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Library-Assistant-master/src/library/assistant/ui/login/login.fxml

```
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:98)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:89)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2540)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:761)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:385)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:672)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.access$100(SceneBuilderApp.java:98)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:524)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$6(UserLibrary.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
   /C:/Users/HabibCse25/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Library-Assistant-master/src/library/assistant/ui/login/login.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:93)
    ... 22 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure scene builder to use the jar your application uses.

Configure them with the Import *JAR/FXML File ...* menu.

[image]

Comment: actually when i double click on the fxml file pop up window says that msg,i gave the image link at the top,i have no options like you said and it happens only that package called login ui,if i double click on fxml file of the other package scene builder opens successfully